# Clearing Group Messages in Telegram using the BOT API

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I need to be able to delete self generated messages by my bot automatically, or clear the entire channel's messages for that matter.
I'm not quite sure I saw anything useful in the Documentation. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage is what you need...

Comment: But the issue is that I cant get the Bot's own message IDs. GetUpdates does not return it.

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage On success, the sent Message is returned. The sent Message returned is including the message_id.